# Modelform ignoring required=True

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm users can use to change their first_name, last_name and email.

I have a clean function to check if the user is trying to change email to an already registered email.

My code:

```
class DjangoUserForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username', type="hidden"),
            Field('first_name'),
            Field('last_name'),
            Field('email'),
        )
        super(DjangoUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username']


    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return email

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DjangoUserForm, self).clean()

        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        if User.objects.exclude(username=username).filter(email=email).exists():
            if not self._errors.has_key('email'):
                from django.forms.util import ErrorList
                self._errors['email'] = ErrorList()
            self._errors['email'].append('Email is used by another user')


        return cleaned_data
```

The function works, but if I try to save the form with an empty email field I get this error: `KeyError at /accounts/user/change/` `'email'` . I have `self.fields['email'].required = True`, and I was expecting django to come up with an "required" error. Anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(DjangoUserForm, self).clean()
    if not self._errors:
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        if not User.objects.exclude(username=username).filter(email=email).exists():
            return cleaned_data
        else:    
            from django.forms.util import ErrorList
            self._errors['email'] = ErrorList()
            self._errors['email'].append('Email is used by another user')
```